# How to export a view to module file with CTool Bulk Export module?

Tags: 7, views, chaos-tool-suite, importing-exporting

I am trying to export some views to module file. It could be done by Views Bulk Export module, but it looks like that Views Bulk Export no longer exists for Views 3??

It (views_export.module) left a node says

```
<?php
// This module has been removed, and this note is left here to ensure
// that users who don't delete their directory before upgrading have
// the code removed and to let people looking for it to know to use
// the CTools bulk export module instead.
```

So how can I export my view now?

Comment: You can use the features module to accomplish this http://drupal.org/project/features

Comment: There are some things that you shouldn't use features for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

@kiamlaluno, the 'export' link in your answer (screenshot) does not require Chaos tool, it comes out of box of views. And it only exports view code, to module file.

To export to module, goto admin/structure/bulk-export, then tick views,

[image]

Comment: I had no idea that existed. Superuseful. Thanks for posting that.

Answer (score 0):

In the page listing all the enable views (admin/structure/views) click on the arrow that you see in the "operations" column; once you click it, you will find the "export" menu item.

[image: screenshot]

The menu item appears after you enabled the Bulk Export module.

[image: screenshot]

The Chaos tool suite module is required from the Views module.